# "chown" for "make install" command?

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, make, makefile

On my Linux server, I accidentally executed `sudo make install` for an application install. I intended to execute `make install` without `sudo` privilege.

How do I change the ownership of all installed dependencies of the application from root to the user, without removing-and-reinstalling them?

Comment: Run `make -n install` (`-n` doesn't actually run the commands, just prints what would be done) to get a listing of what make does. Then either manually or by scraping the terminal reverse what it did when you ran it first time.

Comment: Make -n is a good one. But before you do that check if the Makefile has a 'make uninstall' (e.g. sudo make uninstall ; make install' (second one without sudo).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, there are too many commands(over 30+ lines) associated with the `make` command I executed there. It's impractical for me to uninstall them manually. And, no, I don't have the `make uninstall` in `Makefile`. As a lazy linux novice, I was hoping for one-lined-command to revert my mistake :/